# can we create andorid app with prototyping way

Tags: game-engine

In this image i have shown what i need is :

1. When click on menu the menu should drop down (with animation)
2. When click on date or image or video should open the link page for example on clicking on date it should show the link as shown
3. When click on any date it should show the link page given

[image]

Is it possible with blender or game engine to make a apk file at final export. Any suggestion or help Thanks

Comment: Is your question just about being able to export from the blender game engine to an apk or are you asking how to create those interface elements in the game engine? I'm just having trouble understanding the man focus of your question.

Comment: @RayMairlot Both. 1st to link the pages or the menu to each other (for example given above if click on date the date list should display and if click on date the next page of date detail should display) click on top forward back button also. 2nd is can we export to apk file. Thanks

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need, but separately. I suggest editing your question using the [edit] link below it to remove one of the questions.

Comment: @RayMairlot 1st is to link the button menu with the pages to display the as example given above of date

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. At the current stage (Blender 2.78) following platforms are supported by the BGE:

- Windows
- MacOS
- Linux

Beside of that your request points more to website design rather than a 3D game engine.